# excel distributing 1 print job to 2

Tags: vba, excel

I am selecting ranges from some of my sheets and then printing in a single print job.
This is my code.

```
Sub PrintAll()

Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$12:$R$115"
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$6:$AD$157"
Sheets("Sheet3").Select
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$6:$M$37"
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$6:$R$37"
Sheets("Sheet5").Select
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$6:$R$37"
Sheets("Sheet6").Select
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$6:$R$37"

Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", "Sheet5", "Sheet6")).Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A6").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

However, it is randomly taking Sheet1 in one Print Job and rest of the 5 sheets in another job.
Could you please help.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=92637

It has something to do with the resolution.